# Eclipse plugin project - run command when start

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

When running a project plugin I want to execute a simple method (eg: `System.out.println`), so how where can I do this?

What I'm trying to do is create a project plugin with an activator class and insert inside the Activator constructor the method `System.out.println` but it is not working.

Comment: The Activator does not usually start until something else in the plugin is needed.

Comment: How can I solve the situation?

Comment: What condition should trigger the output? Code in a plugin does not run until something happens to make it run.

Comment: When the Eclipse application instance opens. It's not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something to run during the Eclipse start use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.startup">
  <startup class="example.StartupClass"/>
</extension>
```

where `StartupClass` implements `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup`